# SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number

Tags: delphi, openssl, delphi-2010, indy

I am using TIdTCPClient & TidTCPServer to sending data from Client to Server Through SSL. 
I set the following code at server & Client

**strong text**Server Side

```
   IdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.Mode = sslmServer
   IdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.Method = sslvTLSv1
```

**strong text**Cleint Side

```
   IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.Mode = sslmUnassigned
   IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.Method = sslvTLSv1
```

Error is error:***1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number at Server Side***

When I am executing the Server Application from Delphi IDE, Error message is shown, After click Continue button it establish the connection

At Server & Client both are using the Same DLL Versions

```
    libeay32.dll - 0.9.8.18
     ssleay32.dll - 0.9.8.18
```

I am using Delphi Version 2010 & Indy Version is 10.5.5.

The above error is not occurred in Same system. It is happend in client system. 
the above dlls are placed at Exe Folder.

What am i doing wrong with above code or any wrongly configured..?

thanx in advance

Answer (score 3):

There is no way you can have an established connection after that error occurs. It is an SSL handshake error. OpenSSL would have closed the connection after reporting the error to you.

You are using a bit of an outdated version of Indy. The current version is 10.5.9.

Comment: Can you give the Link to download the Latest Version of 10.5.9?
Why this error is not occurred If Client & Server are in same system?

Comment: Mentioned Repository URLS not working<br/>Repository URLs:  <br/>  
https://svn.atozed.com:444/svn/Indy10  <br/>

Comment: The URLs work fine for me.  If you read the instructions more carefully, you can alternatively download nightly SVN snapshots from the [Fulgan](http://indy.fulgan.com) mirror server instead.